# python error message - Element not visible

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible. or Element is not currently interactable.
```

## How do I fix it?

element:

```
input class="artfld col-all-min ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" formcontrolname="id" maxlength="10" placeholder="身分證字號" type="text"
```

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from PIL import Image
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://mma.sinopac.com/SinoCard/Activity/Register?Code=TLDI')
time.sleep(0.3)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-activity-register/div/div[2]/div/div/section/app-activity-register-verification/form/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input").send_keys("1234")
```

Question 2: 
How to get the element on a button within a pop-up window with python selenium after you click the red button?

element:
button type="button" class="swal2-confirm swal2-styled" aria-label="" style="background-color: rgb(48, 133, 214); border-left-color: rgb(48, 133, 214); border-right-color: rgb(48, 133, 214);">確定 /button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* within the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://mma.sinopac.com/SinoCard/Activity/Register?Code=TLDI")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.artfld.col-all-min.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid[formcontrolname='id']"))).send_keys("YOYO")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://mma.sinopac.com/SinoCard/Activity/Register?Code=TLDI")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='artfld col-all-min ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid' and @formcontrolname='id']"))).send_keys("YOYO")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: YOYO]

Comment: It works. Very useful. Thank you. And I have another question is how to get the element on a button within a pop-up window with python selenium after you click the red button?    I put the contents in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use explicit wait instead of `time.sleep(0.3)` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# wait for an element to appear.
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
waited_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_of_element)))
```